# Allowing CORS without hurting security in HTML5 mobile apps

Tags: angularjs, html, mobile, cors, ionic-framework

I'm developing HTML5 mobile apps for my company. I was getting CORS error when i try to reach the rest api. So i enabled cors for all domains. Now it came back to me after security test. They want me to solve this issue and still reach the api.

The problem is, the app should be usable from all kinds of internet sources. But since this is not a website, i don't have a domain name to allow cors for just that domain. Anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: What exactly is the security concern? the fact that you're using CORS? or that it's wide open using a *. Sounds to me like what you should be using is `*`, if you don't want to restrict who can access it, and that you'll have to explain that to your security council. There is no other option that would preserve the functionality of your rest api other than not allowing CORS at all and forcing your clients to instead use a server to get your data.

Comment: Set up proxy server to handle api data? really not enough known about your architecture to get solid answers from

Comment: @KevinB  The security concern is that i allowed it to all domains. I used *. Can i somehow set a domain for my application and check that at the api level? Or is there another solution for this?

Comment: @charlietfl I have an HTML5 mobile app built with ionic framework and angularjs, a rest api on our server and an asmx services which we call from our rest api. Thats it.

Comment: You can, at the api level, replace the * with the origin requesting the data, if your server-side language allows it. (this is really easy with node.js')

Comment: In addition to the previous recommendations, require a CSRF token for all kinds of requests, including requests that are used to GET data. That way, you can prevent a 3rd party script to easily access your data by just using XHR.